# Can't use find() after Ajax result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Why I can't used `.find()` after my ajax insert the HTML?

This is my [problem](http://jsfiddle.net/w2nscncu/1)

On line 44 I consoled it, but it returns blank. When I code already the html not the ajax result it's working.

Comment: .find("p[data-id='" + contact_id + "']"))  should be .find("[data-id='" + contact_id + "']")) . i can't see ant p tag inside "#modalBodyContact"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the attribute data-id on the p element but it isn't set.

You need to set it...

data-id='+item.id+'

Like you have already done on the buttons

Answer (score 0):

The object will always return blank because you have id'ed the elements correctly

```
  <td><p>'+item.contact_number+'</p></td>
```

should be

```
   <td><p data-id='+item.id+'>'+item.contact_number+'</p></td>
```

Updated the fiddle please have a look

http://jsfiddle.net/w2nscncu/4/